# let $a_1,a_2, ... $be a sequence of real numbers with $a_i \geq 0$.If $\sum_1^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+a_n} < \infty$,then show that

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2,... $be a sequence of real numbers with $a_i  \geq 0$.

If $\sum_1^{\infty}  \dfrac{1}{1+a_n} < \infty$, then show that $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+x_na_n}< \infty $$ for each real sequence $x_1,x_2,...$ with $x_i \geq 0$ and $\underset{n\to\infty}{\liminf}  x_n$ $>0$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: Could you prove this if $x_n=\varepsilon>0$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\liminf x_n > 0$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and an index $N$ with the property that $n \ge N$ implies $x_n \ge \epsilon$.

If $\epsilon \ge 1$ then $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x_n a_n} \le \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + a_n} < \infty $$ and if $0 < \epsilon < 1$ then $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x_n a_n} \le \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon + \epsilon a_n} = \frac 1\epsilon \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + a_n} < \infty.$$